# Как изменить флаги секции ELF файла?

Tags: elf, linux

Можно самому написать утилиту, которая анализирует заголовки файла, находит нужную секцию и выставляет нужные флаги. Но это выглядит избыточно. Нет ли готовой утилиты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать утилиту binutils objcopy:

```
$ objcopy --set-section-flags <name>=<flags>
```